# Restricting query data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting back into mysql after a couple years and have run into a problem. I have a query that works, but I am lost on how to optimize it better.

Here is the query:

```
select
    u.id as 'User',
    count(distinct tr.id) as Trips,
    count(distinct ti.id) as 'Trip Items'
from
    users u
inner join
    user_emails ue on u.id = ue.user_id
inner join
    trips tr on tr.user_id = u.id
inner join
    trip_items ti on ti.trip_id = tr.id
where
    ue.verified = true and ue.is_primary = true
and
    tr.created_at between '2017-02-01 00:00:00' and '2017-02-01 00:59:59'
group by 1
having Trips < 30
```

I essentially need to get a count of all trips and trip items.. but only for those users who have 30 or less trips in the given date range. Right now I am accomplishing that by grouping the results by User, and then performing a 'having'. I'm looking at millions of results on a non-indexed field (created_at). ideally i'd like to just get 1 row back that has total trips, and total trip items. But still applying the "users w/ less than 30 trips" during the query. Is this possible? :)

Just a quick edit, i've tried looking around at other solutions but I am a bit lost on what I should be looking for. I'm not looking for a solution, perhaps just a "go check this out and try that".

Answer (score 1):

`count(distinct)` can be expensive.  Try aggregating *before* doing the `join`.  I think the follow works (this assumes that items are not shared among different trips):

```
select u.id as `User`, tr.Trips, tr.items
from users u inner join
     user_emails ue
     on u.id = ue.user_id inner join
     (select tr.user_id, count(*) as Trips, sum(items) as items
      from trips tr join
           (select ti.trip_id, count(*) as items
            from trip_items ti 
            group by ti.trip_id
           ) ti
           on ti.trip_id = tr.id
       where tr.created_at >= '2017-02-01' and tr.created_at < '2017-02-01 01:00:00'
      group by tr.user_id
      having trips < 30
     ) tr
     on tr.user_id = u.id inner join
where ue.verified = true and ue.is_primary = true
group by 1
```

Comment: I tried giving this a go, it looks like there are some issues and I was unable to resolve them! It seems like this would return the results by user. So "User | Trips | TripItems" - i'm trying to figure out how to get the data back as just "Trips | TripItems", but still applying that 30 or less trip limit to each user. I'll keep trying to fiddle with this to see if I can see where it leads!